# Compiling gstreamer with new glib version

Tags: compilation, gstreamer, centos6, glib

I have CentOS 6.7 installed. I need to compile GStreamer 1.4.5 (or any 1.x) because CentOS distribution has GStreamer 0.10. GStreamer 1.x requires GLib2 >= 2.32 or so, but CentOS has 2.28.8. Therefore I compiled GLib 2.44.1 using specific location /usr/mylibs (as --prefix param).

```
ll /usr/mylibs/lib
total 26008
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 Sep  3 16:48 gio
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 Sep  3 16:48 glib-2.0
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 Sep  3 15:44 libffi-3.2.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     1132 Sep  3 16:48 libgio-2.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       22 Sep  3 16:48 libgio-2.0.so -> libgio-2.0.so.0.4400.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       22 Sep  3 16:48 libgio-2.0.so.0 -> libgio-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  6208700 Sep  3 16:48 libgio-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     1005 Sep  3 16:48 libglib-2.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       23 Sep  3 16:48 libglib-2.0.so -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       23 Sep  3 16:48 libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  3172134 Sep  3 16:48 libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     1059 Sep  3 16:48 libgmodule-2.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Sep  3 16:48 libgmodule-2.0.so -> libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4400.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Sep  3 16:48 libgmodule-2.0.so.0 -> libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    39251 Sep  3 16:48 libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     1060 Sep  3 16:48 libgobject-2.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Sep  3 16:48 libgobject-2.0.so -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Sep  3 16:48 libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  1188762 Sep  3 16:48 libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     1054 Sep  3 16:48 libgthread-2.0.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Sep  3 16:48 libgthread-2.0.so -> libgthread-2.0.so.0.4400.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       26 Sep  3 16:48 libgthread-2.0.so.0 -> libgthread-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     9001 Sep  3 16:48 libgthread-2.0.so.0.4400.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   921042 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre16.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      931 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre16.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre16.so -> libpcre16.so.0.2.5
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre16.so.0 -> libpcre16.so.0.2.5
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   618161 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre16.so.0.2.5
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   893956 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre32.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      931 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre32.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre32.so -> libpcre32.so.0.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre32.so.0 -> libpcre32.so.0.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   593479 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre32.so.0.0.5
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   975726 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre.a
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    46462 Sep  3 16:15 libpcrecpp.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      965 Sep  3 16:15 libpcrecpp.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       19 Sep  3 16:15 libpcrecpp.so -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       19 Sep  3 16:15 libpcrecpp.so.0 -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    43351 Sep  3 16:15 libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      917 Sep  3 16:15 libpcre.la
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    21720 Sep  3 16:15 libpcreposix.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      979 Sep  3 16:15 libpcreposix.la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       21 Sep  3 16:15 libpcreposix.so -> libpcreposix.so.0.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       21 Sep  3 16:15 libpcreposix.so.0 -> libpcreposix.so.0.0.3
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    18917 Sep  3 16:15 libpcreposix.so.0.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       21 Sep  3 16:43 libpcre.so -> /lib/libpcre.so.1.2.5
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   693207 Sep  3 16:47 libpcre.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   693207 Sep  3 16:47 libpcre.so.1.2.5
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 10381922 Sep  3 16:00 libpython2.7.a
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 Sep  3 16:48 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x. 28 root root    20480 Sep  3 16:03 python2.7
```

Now I'm trying to compile GStreamer 1.4.5:

```
export GLIB_CFLAGS="-I/usr/mylibs/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/mylibs/lib/glib-2.0/include" && export GLIB_LIBS="-L/usr/mylibs -L/usr/mylibs/lib/glib-2.0" && export GIO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/mylibs/include -I/usr/mylibs/include/gio-unix-2.0" && export GIO_LIBS="-L/usr/mylibs -L/usr/mylibs/lib/gio" && export PYTHON=/usr/mylibs/bin/python
./configure --prefix=/usr/mylib
or
./configure 
make
```

And it works until this error:

```
Making all in helpers
make[4]: Entering directory `/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5/libs/gst/helpers'
  CC       gst_plugin_scanner-gst-plugin-scanner.o
  CCLD     gst-plugin-scanner
gst_plugin_scanner-gst-plugin-scanner.o: In function `main':
/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5/libs/gst/helpers/gst-plugin-scanner.c:45: undefined reference to `g_malloc'
/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5/libs/gst/helpers/gst-plugin-scanner.c:55: undefined reference to `g_free'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_param_spec_object'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_utf8_validate'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_date_get_month'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_value_get_float'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_checksum_update'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_memdup'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_type_interface_peek'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_value_set_int64'
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_thread_pool_new'
...
../../../gst/.libs/libgstreamer-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_param_spec_ref'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [gst-plugin-scanner] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5/libs/gst/helpers'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5/libs/gst'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5/libs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What have I missed? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on my CentOS 6.3 VM.  I was attempting to build GStreamer 1.4.5 against glib 2.32.4. As shown in [this message thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.gstreamer.embedded/776) it would appear that the incorrect libraries are being linked when you attempt to build (not the 2.0 ones!) Rather than explicitly defining the directory paths in GLIB_CFLAGS you could use PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Locate the pkgconfig directory and ensure packages you have installed reside in there (like glib-2.0, gobject-2.0, gthread-2.0, etc.)  (On my computer my path was: `/usr/local/lib/pkconfig/`.)  I noticed in your directory listing that you have provided you do indeed have pkgconfig.

First, export the variable, then configure, and finally make:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/mylibs/lib/pkgconfig/
./configure
make`

GStreamer should now build correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding how the `*_LIBS` environment variable works.  It should contain the flags needed to link to glib; something like "-L/usr/mylibs/lib -lglib-2.0" should work.

The -L… flag gives the linker an additional place to look for shared libraries (*i.e.*, `libglib-2.0.so`), but in your flags you've given it one directory above what it needs (/usr/mylibs) and a subdirectory (/usr/mylibs/lib/glib-2.0).  The -l… flag tells it what specific library to look for, but you completely omitted it.